# JSON strings are represented as 0

Tags: php, json

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

   $plik = 'users/'.$_SESSION['user'].'/settings.json';

   $file = fopen($plik, "a+");
   @fclose($plik);

   $jsonString = file_get_contents($plik);
   $data = json_decode($jsonString, true);
   if ((isset ($_POST['s_pm'])) && $_POST['s_pm']=="on")
       $data["set_friendreq"] = 1; else $data["set_friendreq"] = 0;
   if (isset($_POST['dsp']))
       $data["set_displayname"] = $_POST['dsp'];

   $newJsonString = json_encode($data);
   file_put_contents($plik, $newJsonString);
}
```

All contents are being saved to JSON file without any problems (like `set_friendreq` because it's a number), but when I try to send a string, a "0" appears in my JSON file (`set_displayname`). Why?

JSON file:

```
{"set_friendreq":0,"set_displayname":"0","lang":"2"}
```

Comment: What is the point of your fopen and fclose?  Your file handler is not used and fclose is supposed to receive a file handler, not the filename.   Instead of listening to the fclose error, I assume you just set it to ignore errors.

Comment: Have you tried printing out $_POST to see what `dsp` contains?  The problem isn't with json/file handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For set_friendreq it's 0 because type is Integer, u init them in the string code.

```
 $data["set_friendreq"] = 1; else $data["set_friendreq"] = 0;
```

$_POST - it's array strings, and in the u try to use json_decode u see "0". Becasue 0 it's string not integer. U had problem with variable types.

Comment: Yes or change this string $data["set_displayname"] = $_POST['dsp']; to $data["set_displayname"] = (int)$_POST['dsp'];

Comment: That isn't the the OP is asking, he is sending a string, not an integer.

Comment: Looking for Code man, $data["set_friendreq"] = 1; else $data["set_friendreq"] = 0; this is not TEXT.

Comment: The OP is asking about displayname not friendreq, reread the question.